# C++ working with templates for integral types, candidate template is ignored

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a class with an overloaded `operator +` for addition. I wish to use it for adding an integral type with one of its integer members. However, the candidate template is being ignored. What is the correct way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class A
    {
    public:
        A(uint32_t a = 0)
        : _a(a)
        { }

        template <class TT, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<TT>::value>::type>
        TT operator + (TT right) { return _a + right; }

    private:
        uint32_t _a;
    };

    class AT : public A<AT>
    {
    public:
        AT() : A(10) { }
    };
int main()
{
    AT at;
    cout<< (at + 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_a(_a)` ? should it not be `_a(a)` ?

Comment: @P.W it should, edited.

Comment: About [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd template parameter `typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<TT>::value>::type` declares an anonymous template parameter, and it can't be deduced in the calling of `at + 10`.

I think what you want might be

```
// specify default value for the 2nd template parameter
template <class TT, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<TT>::value>::type* = nullptr>
T operator + (TT right) { return _a + right; }
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xFv2Rcb5pdnAVA4p)